# Although automated tests are defined on the team foundation build service - it do not run

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, tfsbuild

I have set up a Team Foundation Build Server which builds the code whenever someone tries to check-in. I also set up the build (Via the process tab) to run the automated tests and fail the build on test failure.

The Build indeed builds the code in all configurations, but it doesn't run the tests.

Any ideas why, and what do I need to do in order that the build will run the tests?

Thanks

Comment: do your test assembly names match the regex? are you using the correct test runner? x86 v x64

Comment: Yes, my test dll name is abcTest.dll and the Test configuration in the Build is:  - Run tests in test sources matching **\*Test*.dll;**\*Test*.appx , Target platform: 'X86'
I tried both x86 and x64 just to be safe, but still it doesn't run the tests..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the build outputLocation is configured to "AsConfigured" and the build service is looking for the tests only at the root/bin.
I had to change my configurations in order to output the tests dlls to root/bin (Or supplying the specific path to the build configurations, but in this case you have to mention the agent number , which could change)